# How can I remove the variable inspector on Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed the variable inspector. Then whatever I tried, it is still there..
I tried the code below that I got from searching..

```
jupyter contrib nbextension uninstall --system

jupyter nbextension disable --py widgetsnbextension

jupyter nbextension disable --sys-prefix --py widgetsnbextension
```

Please let me know

Comment: Try these options: **conda remove nbextension** or **pip uninstall nbextension**

Comment: Thanks for this. but when I tried the first one, it showed me   "Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - nbextension
  - remove"           second one is also showed "WARNING: Skipping nbextension as it is not installed."  BUT I still have the variable inspector

Comment: Have you tried using the nbextensions_configurator at <base_url>/nbextensions (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8888/nbextensions)? this is explaned here -> https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator

Answer (score 0):

I figured out on my own. I just deleted every folder that is related to jupyter. Then reinstalled it. It totally worked.